# Can we Post content on Instagram on user's behalf?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to ask whether there is any API endpoint provided by Instagram to post content(like photos, videos etc).
Here is the list of API documentation I have gone through

[Instagram developer forum documentations](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Comment: The documentation has articles about how to share content to instagram. [Instagram mobile sharing](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/). This is a comment, because it is not part of the API, but still might help you.